# Reading attribute popup information from cluster presented points in the map generated via qgis2web?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, javascript, clustering, qgis2web

I have a problem with a web map generated via qgis2web plugin using clusters. I have a batch point data and many of these are on the same location. Because of that I have used cluster for representing the locations. The problem is that when I click on the cluster and got the tree with points at the end and after that click on specific point on of these points doesent showing the popup window (if I have 4 points, one of these is always bad, the popup windows does not appear). [image] Marked point on the screenshot is that point with popup error. I have tried to change cluster circle radius in css folder but I have not found the code part for it.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue between qgis2web and Leaflet.markercluster: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/505

There is an "easy" workaround: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/431

The idea is to specify [`spiderfyDistanceMultiplier`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-options) option when instantiating the `L.markerClusterGroup`, but this requires that you can pass options to that factory.

In the case of qgis2web, I am not sure you can specify such options unfortunately.

If you can customize the JavaScript, you could however tweak Leaflet.markercluster plugin so that it uses a different `spiderfyDistanceMultiplier` option value by default:

```js
// Increase spiderfyDistanceMultiplier by default
// in order to force spiderfied Circle Markers to extend outside
// the cluster icon, and be clickable (so that user can open the popup if any).
L.MarkerClusterGroup.mergeOptions({
  spiderfyDistanceMultiplier: 2
});
```

Place this code in a `<script>` tag *after* Leaflet.markercluster script. It should work even if it is executed after qgis2web JavaScript code.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to set this value by default in qgis2web?

Comment: @TomChadwin Thanks for caring about this issue! That might help in case qgis2web always uses Circle Marker type (instead of icon-based marker), but only for small clusters. If there are more than a couple markers, the spiderfication might become enourmous… If I understand correctly, qgis2web does not provide a lot of options for customization, hence the need to choose carefully a default value? Maybe we could improve on Leaflet.markercluster side as well.

Comment: It's probably a little more complex. I'll pick the discussion up on https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/505.

Answer (score 2):

Using the information provided by @ghybs, a possible fix for this issue is now in qgis2web 2.31.0. Please try that and see whether is solves the issue you are having. It adds the option `spiderfyDistanceMultiplier: 2` to clustered layers.